# Bash command only executes the first time around

Tags: python, bash, shell, nmap

I have the following nmap command:

```
nmap -n -p 25 10.11.1.1-254 --open | grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' | cut -d" " -f5
```

This produces a list of ip addresses which I'm trying to pass to the following python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python


# Python tool to check a range of hosts for SMTP servers that respond to VRFY requests

import socket
import sys
from socket import error as socket_error

# Read the username file
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    usernames = f.read().splitlines()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_ip = sys.argv[2]

print("****************************")
print("Results for: " + host_ip)
try: 
    c = s.connect((host_ip,25))
    banner=s.recv(1024)

    #Send VRFY requests and print result
    for user in usernames:
        s.send('VRFY ' + user + '\r\n')
        result = s.recv(1024)
        print(result)

    print("****************************")
    #Close Socket
    s.close()

#If error is thrown
except socket_error as serr:
    print("\nNo SMTP verify for " +host_ip)
    print("****************************")
```

I've tried to do this with the following command, however it's only running the script over the first ip that it finds:

```
./smtp_verify.py users.txt $(nmap -n -p 25 10.11.1.1-254 --open | grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' | cut -d" " -f5)
```

I've also tried to do this with:

```
for $ip in (nmap -n -p 25 10.11.1.1-254 --open | grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' | cut -d" " -f5); do ./smtp_verify.py users.txt $ip done
```

However I receive a syntax error for it which suggests to me I can't pass pipes this way?

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not consciously use `for` loop for parsing command output, see [DontReadLinesWithFor](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor), rather use a [Process-Subtitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) syntax with a `while` loop

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    ./smtp_verify.py users.txt "$line"
done< <(nmap -n -p 25 10.11.1.1-254 --open | grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' | cut -d" " -f5)
```

And for the error you are likely seeing, you are *NOT* using command-substitution `$(..)` syntax properly to run the piped commands, the commands should have been enclosed around `()` with a `$` before it. Something like,

```
#!/bin/bash

for ip in $(nmap -n -p 25 10.11.1.1-254 --open | grep '[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\.[0-9]\{1,3\}' | cut -d" " -f5); do 
    ./smtp_verify.py users.txt "$ip" 
done
```

And remember to always double-quote shell variables to avoid [Word Splitting](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/wordsplit) done by the shell.

Comment: Very educational, thank-you! Clearly, I have a lot left to learn!